# Перенос значений в новую матрицу.

Tags: c

Всем привет. Вот есть такая задачка:

> Дана квадратная матрица порядка N. В матрице вычислить среднее арифметическое положи-тельных элементов, стоящих на главной диагонали.

Я тут подумал, и  решил сделать так... Задать массив, далее высчитать положительные элементы. Потом их перенести в новый массив и подсчитать сумму пол. элементов, стоящих на главной диагонали...

Как мне положительные элементы перенести в новый массив? нужно создать новую переменную или есть другой способ?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совершенно необязательно заводить новый массив. Вам нужно лишь знать количество положительных элементов и их сумму.

*Можете просто "пробежаться" по диагонали матрицы, складывая положительные элементы в одну переменную, а их число - в другую.*

---

Т.е решение задачки на русском языке можно записать так:

```
Для каждого элемента массива, стоящего на главное диагонали:
    Если элемент > 0, То:
        В сумму прибавить этот элемент, увеличить число положительных элементов на 1

Результат работы = Сумма / Количество
```

*Теперь осталось только оформить это все, как программу.*

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но я как-то не особо представляю как это написать на С ("пробежаться" по диагонали матрицы). :(
Т.е. если у меня 9 элементов, то мне нужно завести переменную, вообщем что-то этого?:
a= i[1] + i[5] + i[9];

Comment: @Tim Пусть i, j - индексы по горизонтали и вертикали. Тогда, если матрица 3x3 записана, например, как `int matrix[3 * 3];`, то обращаться к ее элементам можно так: `matrix[j * 3 + i]`. Если проводить простые аналогии, то это означает, что мы матрицу (квадрат) размера `3x3 = 9`, "распрямили" в строчку из 9 элементов.

Comment: @Tim Т.е, грубо говоря, у нас все строчки исходной матрицы становятся друг за другом в одну большую строчку длины 9. Теперь осталось только как устроены индексы элементов главной диагонали и воспользоваться формулой `matrix[j * 3 + i]`.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, буду решать)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем новый массив? Зачем все это?

```
int a[N][N], b=0, c=0;

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   if(a[i][i]>=0)
   {
      b=a[i][i]+b;
      c++;
   }
}

cout<<b/c<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Для одномерного массива так:

```
type array[N*N], sum=0;
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i<N*N; i+=N+1)
{
    if(array[i]<=0) continue;
    sum+=array[i];
    count++;
}
cout << sum/count << endl;
```

Промежуточный массив не нужен. Вместо type поставить int, float или какой там тип у твоей матрицы.